# Opening a text file with Excel 16 instead of Notepad

Tags: windows, windows-registry, microsoft-excel-2016, notepad

I have an accounting software program that produces all files as .txt files.  Before upgrading to Excel 16, I was able to choose Excel as the program to open those files.  With Excel 16, I have not been able to make that choice.  I've searched for a solution and made the following changes as others have recommended:

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\EXCEL.EXE\shell\open\command

(default)    REG_SZ    "C:\Program Files(x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\EXCEL.EXE" "%1"

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts.txt\UserChoice

Progrid  REG_SZ Applications\EXCEL.EXE

i am currently at a loss as to how to proceed.  I've spent hours searching for a solution to no avail.

Thanks in advance, F

Comment: What does the text look like (does it have a standard structure, like a CSV file named with a .txt extension?  Have you tried importing it the way you would with a CSV file?  If it is structured like a CSV, have you tried renaming the file extension to .csv?

Answer (score 0):

right click the .txt file > Open with.. > 'Choose another app' > (tick "Always use this app to open .txt files") go to 'more app' > 'look for another app in this pc' > navigate to C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\EXCEL.EXE

That shall do it..

Answer (score -1):

I have "office 360" and this doesn't work. However I found excel.exe in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16 and used that. Of course that means it is a 32 bit version, but I guess that is what I have.